# how to use asterisk-java for getting output "sip show peers" cli command

Tags: java, command-line-interface, asterisk

Actually, I'm using Asterik Manager API for java. But, it's just for login and register asterisk.
I wonder can get the output of "sip show peers" command that showing user status.

thanks in advance.

Comment: You say you use "Asterik Manager API for Java". Can you please direct me to this API?

Answer (score 0):

Use the AMI command SIPpeers, however that is exposed in the java interface.  To get specific information on a peer, use SIPshowpeer.